# Where is the equivalent in Rust of the msgpack Timestamp class in Python

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde, msgpack

In Python, when decoding a messagepack message that contains a timestamp, the code in the msgpack library (Timestamp class) is pretty straightforward as it just takes the bytes it finds for a field and converts them as copied from the lib below:

```
def from_bytes(b):
    """Unpack bytes into a `Timestamp` object.

    Used for pure-Python msgpack unpacking.

    :param b: Payload from msgpack ext message with code -1
    :type b: bytes

    :returns: Timestamp object unpacked from msgpack ext payload
    :rtype: Timestamp
    """
    if len(b) == 4:
        seconds = struct.unpack("!L", b)[0]
        nanoseconds = 0
    elif len(b) == 8:
        data64 = struct.unpack("!Q", b)[0]
        seconds = data64 & 0x00000003FFFFFFFF
        nanoseconds = data64 >> 34
    elif len(b) == 12:
        nanoseconds, seconds = struct.unpack("!Iq", b)
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            "Timestamp type can only be created from 32, 64, or 96-bit byte objects"
        )
    return Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)
```

I am massively struggling to achieve the same behavior in Rust. For simplicity's sake, this a simple struct:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize)]
struct ReceivedMessage {
    a_string: String,
    a_value: f64,
    a_timestamp: ?????      // <--- what to put here?
}
```

When calling `rmp_serde::from_slice(&'a [u8])` with the binary messagepack message I get

> called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Syntax("invalid type:
> newtype struct, expected byte array")

and it just doesn't matter what type I put for `a_timestamp`. I tried `SystemTime`, `i64`, `f64` and `serde_as` with `TimestampSeconds` etc. I then tried using `Vec<u8>` and `serde_bytes` as well as writing a custom converter with `serde::conv!` All to no avail and always the same error message. There doesn't seem to be any comprehensive tutorial online on this. (The other fields in the struct deserialize just fine as I found out when debugging).
If it matters, the binary message comes as a map, i.e. with the field names and not as an array.

It seems to me that this should be easy as Python has all this functionality built-in into the msgpack library. So how can I decode a timestamp in Rust?

I am using the newest crate versions

```
rmp-serde = "1.1.2"
serde = "1"
serde_derive = "1"
serde_with = "3.4"
serde_bytes = "0.11"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rmp-serde` doesn't have this feature implemented, see [#298](https://github.com/3Hren/msgpack-rust/issues/298).

There is some code from the issue that appears to follow the Msgpack standard:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SomeStruct {
    #[serde(
        serialize_with = "serialize_mp_date_secs",
        deserialize_with = "deserialize_mp_date_secs"
    )]
    date: u64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename = "_ExtStruct")]
pub struct ExtStruct((i8, ByteBuf));

fn u32_from_bytebuf(buf: &ByteBuf) -> Result<u32, TryFromSliceError> {
    let bytes = buf.as_slice().try_into()?;
    Ok(u32::from_be_bytes(bytes))
}

fn u64_from_bytebuf(buf: &ByteBuf) -> Result<u64, TryFromSliceError> {
    let bytes = buf.as_slice().try_into()?;
    Ok(u64::from_be_bytes(bytes))
}

pub fn serialize_mp_date_secs<S>(secs: &u64, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let data64 = *secs;
    let ext = if (secs >> 34) == 0 {
        if (data64 & 0xffffffff00000000) == 0 {
            // timestamp 32
            let data32 = data64 as u32;
            ExtStruct((-1, ByteBuf::from(data32.to_be_bytes())))
        } else {
            // timestamp 64
            ExtStruct((-1, ByteBuf::from(data64.to_be_bytes())))
        }
    } else {
        // timestamp 96
        let mut bytes = 0u32.to_be_bytes().to_vec();
        let mut secs = (data64 as i64).to_be_bytes().to_vec();
        bytes.append(&mut secs);
        ExtStruct((-1, ByteBuf::from(bytes)))
    };
    ext.serialize(serializer)
}

pub fn deserialize_mp_date_secs<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<u64, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let ExtStruct((ext_type, buf)) = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    if ext_type != -1 {
        return Err(de::Error::custom("Invalid extension type (!=-1)"));
    }

    let sec = match buf.len() {
        4 => {
            let sec = u32_from_bytebuf(&buf).map_err(|e| {
                de::Error::custom(format!("Failed to get u32 from bytebuf ({})", e))
            })?;
            sec as u64
        }
        8 => {
            let data64 = u64_from_bytebuf(&buf).map_err(|e| {
                de::Error::custom(format!("Failed to get u64 from bytebuf ({})", e))
            })?;
            data64 & 0x00000003ffffffff
        }
        12 => {
            u64_from_bytebuf(&buf)
                .map_err(|e| de::Error::custom(format!("Failed to get u64 from bytebuf ({})", e)))?
                + 4
        }
        n => {
            return Err(de::Error::custom(format!(
                "Invalid data len {n} (valid sizes are 4, 8 and 12)"
            )))
        }
    };

    Ok(sec)
}
```

However, this seems to only care for precision up to the second.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding this. I thought I had searched everywhere... But I must honestly say that a library/crate that has reached version 1 should be feature-complete. And it's not even mentioned anywhere. Quite a bumpy start into my Rust adventure.

Comment: @Sebastian rmp-serde don't have a lot of support also I believe timestamp is an extension maybe you could try https://lib.rs/crates/msgpacker (look better but no serde). Also in Rust we generally use bincode that why there is not a lot of support of messagepack

Comment: I have to use messagepack as I can't control the source.
msgpacker complained it didn't know how to treat Vec<String> even though it should have been possible out of the box, so I disregarded it. Also msgpack_simple has a very nice syntax but seems outdated as it produced different bytes than rmp_serde. So I went with rmp_serde still, and got it to work using your answer!

Comment: I have added an answer to the GitHub issue that also accounts for nanoseconds: https://github.com/3Hren/msgpack-rust/issues/298#issuecomment-1808011414